Bizarre drain issue in Bosch SilencePlus
Bosch SilencePlus 50 dBA
It seems like there's something odd going on with either a sensor or the control board.
I've tried cleaning out the impeller and drain hose, and they're clean and clear, and it always drains fine when triggered manually. Video of drain flow
Here's the pattern:
After the first rinse cycle, it cycles the impeller 3 times, stops, makes a very faint click sound a number of times, is quiet for a few minutes, cycles the impeller 3 more times, and then beeps and says it's clean, even though it didn't drain. Then, if I manually trigger it to drain (by power cycling the dishwasher and holding down the start button), it always drains just fine. Here's an audio recording of the final impeller cycles before it beeps as clean:
Audio recording of impeller cycles
When triggered manually, the flow is quite good, the hose isn't kinked or clogged, and the impeller is functioning properly.
Unfortunately, there's no panel for error codes on this model, so I'm not sure what to look at next.
